Can the Riemann Tensor be Decomposed Using the Ricci and Weyl Tensors?
Good morning,
I am studying General Relativity, specifically the Riemann tensor, which is used to identify curvature in a manifold and thus determine if there is an actual gravitational field.
While reading Carol's book on the topic, I came across a discussion where the curvature tensor (and tensors in general) are decomposed into subspaces, with symmetric/antisymmetric parts and traceless components. He then introduces the Ricci tensor as the trace of the Riemann tensor (contracting the first and third indices) and the Weyl tensor, but doesn't elaborate much further.
My question is: Is it possible to decompose the Riemann tensor using the Ricci and Weyl tensors? Specifically, can the Riemann tensor be expressed in terms of these tensors to separate its contributions?
Are there any references that explain this decomposition in more detail?
Thank you and have a great day!

You probably mean Sean Carroll's book. If you can afford to put the metric into that decomposition is the answer not obvious from the very definition of the Weyl tensor?

Yes, see e.g. https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/it3/texts/curvaturelike.pdf

Using the moving-frame formalism the (1,3)-tensor $W$ called Weyl tensor is given by $W=W^i_{jkt}\theta^k\otimes\theta^t\otimes\theta^j\otimes e_i$ with components
$$W^i_{jkt}=R^{i}_{jkt}-\frac{1}{m-2}(R_{ik}\delta^j_t-R_{jk}\delta^i_t+R_{jt}\delta^i_k-R_{it}\delta^j_k)+\frac{S}{2(m-1)(m-2)}(\delta^i_k\delta^j_t-\delta^i_t\delta^j_k).$$
Note that the (1,3) version of $W$ is invariant under a conformal change of the metric, while the (0,4) version of Weyl tensor, with $W_{ijkt}=W^i_{jkt}$, is not conformally invariant.
$W^{i}_{jkt}$ has the same symmetries of $R^i_{jkt}$ and satisfies the first Bianchi identity and it can be showed that any of its traces is identically zero. The Weyl tensor represents the totally-free trace part of the curvature tensor. 
A further decomposition can be given introducing the tensors $U$ and $V$ defined as
$$U_{ijkt}=\frac{S}{m(m-1)}(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jt}-\delta_{it}\delta_{jk})\\V_{ijkt}=\frac{1}{m-2}(\dot R_{ik}\delta_{jt}+\dot R_{jt}\delta_{ik}-\dot R_{it}\delta_{jk}-\dot R_{jk}\delta_{it}),$$ where the dotted tensor is the trace-less Ricci (given a 2-covariant tensor G, we set $\dot G=G-\frac{1}{dim(M)}tr(G)g$).
You can check that these 3 tensors are mutually orthogonal and satisfies $Riem=W+U+V$ and $|Riem|^2=|W|^2+|U|^2+|V|^2$.
You can write all this in global form using Kulkarni-Nomizu product.

Thank you very much!

It's been a pleasure @Lip!
